Filter the parent node with button to create treemap in D3.js
First of all sorry for eventual mistake i'm not fluent in english,
I begin a project with d3.js and i try to filter my data thanks to button.
Let me explain i want to get the name of Portfolio children to create my button.
And after it when click on it display a treemap with the children of Competences which his parent his the value of the button (see my Json File)
I never did D3js before i'm really lost
JSON FIle :
{
    "name": "Portfolio",
    "children": [
        {
            "name": "Htonic",
            "children": [
                {
                    "name": "Competences",
                    "children": [
                        {
                            "name": "Concevoir",
                            "children": [
                                {
                                    "name": "encodage",
                                    "value": 10,
                                    "colname": "level3"
                                }
                            ]
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "Comprendre",
                            "children": [
                                {
                                    "name": "scénariser",
                                    "value": 10,
                                    "colname": "level3"
                                },
                                {
                                    "name": "interview",
                                    "value": 10,
                                    "colname": "level3"
                                }
                            ]
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "Exprimer",
                            "children": [
                                {
                                    "name": "lumière",
                                    "value": 10,
                                    "colname": "level3"
                                },
                                {
                                    "name": "cadrage",
                                    "value": 10,
                                    "colname": "level3"
                                }
                            ]
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "Developper",
                            "children": [
                                {
                                    "name": "encodage",
                                    "value": 10,
                                    "colname": "level3"
                                },
                                {
                                    "name": "compression",
                                    "value": 10,
                                    "colname": "level3"
                                }
                            ]
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "Entreprendre",
                            "children": [
                                {
                                    "name": "encodage",
                                    "value": 10,
                                    "colname": "level3"
                                },
                                {
                                    "name": "compression",
                                    "value": 10,
                                    "colname": "level3"
                                },
                                {
                                    "name": "sémiologie",
                                    "value": 10,
                                    "colname": "level3"
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "name": "Soft-Skills",
                    "children": [
                        {
                            "name": "Creativite",
                            "size": "1"
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "Curiosite",
                            "size": "2"
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "Adaptabilite",
                            "size": "3"
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "Perseverance",
                            "size": "4"
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "Empathie",
                            "size": "5"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "name": "Hard-Skills",
                    "children": [
                        {
                            "name": "Photoshop",
                            "taille": "1"
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "Illustrator",
                            "taille": "2"
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "Figma",
                            "taille": "3"
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "Canva",
                            "taille": "4"
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "Wordpress",
                            "taille": "5"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "Trivial Trégor",
            "children": [
                {
                    "name": "Competences",
                    "children": [
                        {
                            "name": "Concevoir",
                            "children": [
                                {
                                    "name": "Marsupilami",
                                    "value": 10,
                                    "colname": "level3"
                                }
                            ]
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "Comprendre",
                            "children": [
                                {
                                    "name": "scénariser",
                                    "value": 10,
                                    "colname": "level3"
                                },
                                {
                                    "name": "interview",
                                    "value": 10,
                                    "colname": "level3"
                                }
                            ]
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "Exprimer",
                            "children": [
                                {
                                    "name": "lumière",
                                    "value": 10,
                                    "colname": "level3"
                                },
                                {
                                    "name": "cadrage",
                                    "value": 10,
                                    "colname": "level3"
                                }
                            ]
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "Developper",
                            "children": [
                                {
                                    "name": "encodage",
                                    "value": 10,
                                    "colname": "level3"
                                },
                                {
                                    "name": "compression",
                                    "value": 10,
                                    "colname": "level3"
                                }
                            ]
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "Entreprendre",
                            "children": [
                                {
                                    "name": "encodage",
                                    "value": 10,
                                    "colname": "level3"
                                },
                                {
                                    "name": "compression",
                                    "value": 10,
                                    "colname": "level3"
                                },
                                {
                                    "name": "sémiologie",
                                    "value": 10,
                                    "colname": "level3"
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "name": "Soft-Skills",
                    "children": [
                        {
                            "name": "Creativite",
                            "size": "1"
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "Curiosite",
                            "size": "2"
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "Adaptabilite",
                            "size": "3"
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "Perseverance",
                            "size": "4"
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "Empathie",
                            "size": "5"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "name": "Hard-Skills",
                    "children": [
                        {
                            "name": "Photoshop",
                            "taille": "1"
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "Illustrator",
                            "taille": "2"
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "Figma",
                            "taille": "3"
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "Canva",
                            "taille": "4"
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "Wordpress",
                            "taille": "5"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}

JS File :
//Générer le Treemap avec D3.js

// Taille du graph
const margin = { top: 10, right: 10, bottom: 10, left: 10 },
    width = 445 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 445 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

// Choix div + taille du svg dans la div
const svg = d3.select("#treemap")
    .append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform",
        `translate(${margin.left}, ${margin.top})`);

// Lecture données
d3.json("data-plus.json").then(function (data) {
    // Trie des données de façon hiérarchique
    const root = d3.hierarchy(data).sum(function (d) { return d.value })   // Compute the numeric value for each entity // Récupération de la valeur de chaque cellules


    const color = d3.scaleOrdinal()
        .domain(["Comprendre", "Concevoir", "Exprimer", "Developper", "Entreprendre"])
        .range(["red", "orange", "yellow", "green", "blue"])

    const opacity = d3.scaleLinear()
        .domain([10, 30])
        .range([.5, 1])
    // Positionnement des cellules
    d3.treemap()
        .size([width, height])
        .padding(2)
        (root)
    // Ajout des cellules
    svg
        .selectAll("rect")
        .data(root.leaves())
        .join("rect")
        .attr('x', function (d) { return d.x0; })
        .attr('y', function (d) { return d.y0; })
        .attr('width', function (d) { return d.x1 - d.x0; })
        .attr('height', function (d) { return d.y1 - d.y0; })
        .style("stroke", "black")
        .style("fill", function (d) { return color(d.parent.data.name) })
        .style("opacity", 1)


    // Ajout des Mots-clés
    svg
        .selectAll("text")
        .data(root.leaves())
        .join("text")
        .attr("x", function (d) { return d.x0 + 5 })    // Position texte (augmenter valeur pour bouger vers la droite)
        .attr("y", function (d) { return d.y0 + 20 })    // Position txt Verticale ( augmenter pour faire descendre)
        .text(function (d) { return d.data.name })
        .attr("font-size", "12px")
        .attr("fill", "white")

});

and HTML file :
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/d3@7"></script>
    <div class="button-container" id="buttons"></div>
    <div id="treemap"></div>
    <script src="treemap.js"></script>
</body>

</html>

I try with the enter() update() exit() method but i think how i filter my value is not correct

You can use JS array methods for filtering and handling user interactions. The d3 treemap code can be a separate function that you call on click.
